# Can my Whatsapp calls and messages be tracked and recorded by my mobile network carrier?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, carriers

First of all sorry if this is the wrong section cuz I don't know where to post this question :/

I have been using Whatsapp for a while now and I'm wondering if it ever possible for my mobile network carrier to know who am I contacting on Whatsapp and record my call and text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is utterly IMpossible, but it's certainly improbable. They'd have to carefully monitor every bit of your network traffic, and as WhatsApp encrypts all of their traffic, your carrier would then have to break that encryption which is no small task.

The alternative is for your carrier to have installed some sort of monitoring software on your phone pre-purchase to track all your actions before they even reach WhatsApp. If they're a large provider, we'd all know if they were doing this by now, as the class action suits would be flying. People take their security very seriously and regularly tear apart what's going on inside their phones to ensure they're not being spied on.

So for all practical purposes, no, your carrier doesn't know who you're contacting or what you're doing in WhatsApp. The most they likely know is THAT you're using WhatsApp. No need to worry.

Comment: But they will for sure know that I'm using whatsapp and the time duration I'm using it for a call, right?

Comment: Not exactly. They'll be capable of recognizing the IP addresses you're communicating with and that they're WhatsApp's servers, if they care. Which they don't. The most they'll use that for is internal data metrics for understanding how their network's being used. They can surmise that you might be using it for a call based on the amount of data flowing, but they can't actually know for certain what you're doing. Perhaps you can explain a little bit about your specific concern so I can address it better?

Comment: Well to be exact, the sim in registered with my friend's ID, so if my friend chooses to know who am I calling in Whatsapp and the time duration of my call, will he be able to get info about that from my network carrier?

Comment: Nope. In order to get those kinds of records, he'd likely need a subpoena. Carriers don't give out records that detailed. They will usually make available how much data was used at what time, but no information about where it went. That requires much deeper records that they don't just hand out. The law would likely need to be involved, and they still wouldn't know who you talked to. Just a rough guess at how long you may have talked to SOMEONE.

Comment: While I'd *generally* agree, there is more to it: some carriers forbid VoIP in their contracts, so they'd be interested to know when you're placing a VoIP call. Moreover, [WA encryption is pretty weak and sometimes not even available](http://www.myce.com/news/users-shouldnt-trust-on-whatsapps-end-to-end-encryption-75939/) (e.g. when the "other end" is using iOS), so I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Sure, but that's easily handled by simply filtering a specific type of traffic. However yes, I wasn't thinking about the fact that they can, indeed, recognize SIP traffic differently, assuming WhatsApp even uses SIP or a standard VoIP protocol. So still, the worst-case scenario is that the carrier can recognize THAT a call is taking place. But not to whom.